# Access this.<module> from within Nuxt plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

Is there any way I can access a JS API exposed by a Nuxt module from within a client-side plugin?

Context: I'm using Buefy/Bulma, which is loaded like this in nuxt.config.js:

```
modules: [
    ['nuxt-buefy', {css: false}],
],
```

Buefy exposes `this.$buefy.<etc>` which is accessible from components.

But I want to access this API from within a client-side plugin, utils.js, which is loaded like this:

```
plugins: ['~/plugins/utils.js'],
```

And utils.js itself:

```
export default ({app}, inject) => {
    inject('myUtil', (msg, isErr) => {
        app.$buefy; //<-- undefined
        ....
```

I assume this is an ordering issue, i.e. Buefy is being loaded after my plugin or something. I can't do this in a static JS file loaded via `meta.scripts` as that won't have access to the app (I assume).

Anything I can do here?

Comment: Maybe try `export default ({ app, $buefy }, inject) => {` and use it directly as `$buefy`.

Comment: Same result (`undefined`), alas...

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your plugin js file

```
import { ToastProgrammatic as toast } from 'buefy';

export default (_, inject) => {
  inject('appHelper', {
    displayToast(duration = null, msg = null, position = null, type = null) {
      toast.open({
        duration: duration || 3000,
        message: msg || 'Update Successful',
        position: position || 'is-bottom-left',
        type: type || 'is-success',
      });
    },
  });
};
```